# Write a method that will take in a time in 24 hour format (1430) and return time in 12 hour format (2:30pm)

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to use the SimpleDateFormat to get the user input but I keep getting the error, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Not really sure how I can get the string to take in the information and convert it or if it's possible to do this way. Any comments that could steer me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class takeTime {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print( "Please enter a time: " );
        String now = reader.nextLine();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        System.out.println( format.format(now));
    }

}
```

Comment: Convert "now" to a `Date` object first using the `HHmm` date format

Comment: Don't you need two formatters -- one to parse using the input format and the other to print using output format. OTOH, if this is an assignment your professor might have intended for you to do all that parsing and converting on your own, it is not very difficult is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the input from the user to a `Date` first.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print( "Please enter a time: " );
String now = reader.nextLine();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").parse(now);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
System.out.println( format.format(date));
```